# Excel: search for string in row and find column

Tags: excel, search, find, worksheet-function

I would like to search a row for a string and get the column number if there is such a string.

Is this possible by using worksheet functions in Excel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `MATCH` to give the position, e.g. you can search in row 2 for "xyz" like this

`=MATCH("xyz",2:2,0)`

If "xyz" is found first in J2 you get 10

if you want partial matches then you can use wildcards like

`=MATCH("*xyz*",2:2,0)`

so if F2 contains [abc **xyz** 344] you get a match with that and formula returns 6

Answer (score 2):

I believe `VLOOKUP` is the best for you.
There's also others like `HLOOKUP`, `LOOKUP` and `SEARCH`

Answer (score 0):

If the lookup value is "value" and it is in row 1
    =MATCH("value",1:1,0)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
A1      A2      A3      A4 
111 aaa sss bbb,
```

you could write something of this sort:

```
=FIND("$", CELL("address",OFFSET($A$2, 0,MATCH(111,A2:D2,1)-COLUMN($A$2)+1)), 2)
```

Ugly, but works (assuming that's what you were looking for)...